# Cannot use sqlplus in linux

Tags: linux, oracle, sqlplus

I'm trying to run the sql command line "sqlplus" on my linux machine using the command "sqlplus / as sysdba". I get the following:

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on Tue Sep 20 12:28:29 2016

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connected to an idle instance.

then when I write statrup command I get :

```
ORA-01078: failure in processing system parameters
LRM-00109: could not open parameter file '/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/dbs/initSID.ora'
SQL> exit
Disconnected
```

I looked online for a solution and I followed whats written in https://community.oracle.com/thread/2178662 
[enter link description here](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2178662)
I tried the following commands before starting sqlplus again :
export ORACLE_SID=SID
env|grep ORA|sort  which give me the following information:

```
ORACLE_BASE=/u01/app/oracle
ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1
ORACLE_HOSTNAME= HOSENAME
ORACLE_SID=SID
ORACLE_UNQNAME=DB11G
```

last I wrote cat /etc/oratab ,, with the following result

```
# This file is used by ORACLE utilities.  It is created by root.sh
# and updated by the Database Configuration Assistant when creating
# a database.

# A colon, ':', is used as the field terminator.  A new line terminates
# the entry.  Lines beginning with a pound sign, '#', are comments.
#
# Entries are of the form:
#   $ORACLE_SID:$ORACLE_HOME:<N|Y>:
#
# The first and second fields are the system identifier and home
# directory of the database respectively.  The third filed indicates
# to the dbstart utility that the database should , "Y", or should not,
# "N", be brought up at system boot time.
#
# Multiple entries with the same $ORACLE_SID are not allowed.
#
```

At the end, I tried to check if my database is running using the following command  ps -ef|grep pmon
which showed me

```
oracle   18023 11347  0 12:38 pts/5    00:00:00 grep --color=auto pmon
oracle   19686     1  0 Aug23 ?        00:05:11 ora_pmon_apertureSID
```

So now I'm not sure whats the problem. I need to run the sqlplus
Can anyone guide me

Comment: hi, did you try a "startup" or "startup pfile=..."?

Answer (score 1):

Your databases SID is "apertureSID" not pure "SID".

`export ORACLE_SID=apertureSID`

moreover, it is recommended to have Oracle SID max. length 12 character, usually all uppercase.

Comment: Yes I just solved the problem by changing  that. Thanks a lot

Answer (score -1):

So the solution was to change the ORACLE_SID using the command `.oraenv` 
then it promoted me to change `ORACLE_SID= [SID] ? ApertureSID`
Finally I just checked that using the command `env |grep ORACLE` and re-run the sqlplus. WORKED

very helpful tutorial : http://blog.dbvisit.com/whats-going-on-connected-to-an-idle-instance-but-database-is-running/